# tsql : how do you query with dashes in column names?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the query

```
select * from products p, products_temp t 
where p.ManufacturerPartNumber = t.[INV-PRICE-VENDOR-PART]
```

where the column names have dashes in them which SQL Server 2005 seems to automatically add brackets to.  What is the correct way of accessing this in a query? I've tried with brackets and without the brackets and just end up with errors.

the error I get from sql mgmt studio is

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because you have repeated WHERE twice in your statement. Got nothing to do with the square brackets which you will need because of the dashes.

Comment: Don't worry. Do it all the time. At least you copy-pasted and didn't rewrite the query but correctly this time and have us all scratching our heads :)

Answer (score 0):

use "current" join syntax:

```
SELECT
    *
    from products                 p
        INNER JOIN products_temp  t  ON p.ManufacturerPartNumber = t.[INV-PRICE-VENDOR-PART]
```